# convert char[] of hexadecimal numbers to char[] of letters corresponding to the hexadecimal numbers in ascii table and reversing it

Tags: c++

I have a `char a[]` of hexadecimal characters like this:

> "315c4eeaa8b5f8aaf9174145bf43e1784b8fa00dc71d885a804e5ee9fa40b16349c146fb778cdf2d3aff021dfff5b403b510d0d0455468aeb98622b137dae857553ccd8883a7bc37520e06e515d22c954eba5025b8cc57ee59418ce7dc6bc41556bdb36bbca3e8774301fbcaa3b83b220809560987815f65286764703de0f3d524400a19b159610b11ef3e"

I want to convert it to letters corresponding to each hexadecimal number like this:

```
68656c6c6f = hello
```

and store it in `char b[]` and then do the reverse

I don't want a block of code please, I want explanation and what libraries was used and how to use it.

Thanks

Comment: *much* better question now. ok then.

Comment: Libraries? That's like two lines of code...

Comment: And have you decided which code does it use? ASCII, Latin-1, UTF-8?

Comment: it's written in the title (ascii)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple piece of code to do the trick:

```
unsigned int hex_digit_value(char c)
{
    if ('0' <= c && c <= '9') { return c - '0'; }
    if ('a' <= c && c <= 'f') { return c + 10 - 'a'; }
    if ('A' <= c && c <= 'F') { return c + 10 - 'A'; }
    return -1;
}

std::string dehexify(std::string const & s)
{
    std::string result(s.size() / 2);

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i != s.size(); ++i)
    {
        result[i] = hex_digit_value(s[2 * i]) * 16
                  + hex_digit_value(s[2 * i + 1]);
    }

    return result;
}
```

**Usage:**

```
char const a[] = "12AB";

std::string s = dehexify(a);
```

**Notes:**

- A proper implementation would add checks that the input string length is even and that each digit is in fact a valid hex numeral.
- Dehexifying has nothing to do with ASCII. It just turns *any* hexified sequence of nibbles into a sequence of bytes. I just use `std::string` as a convenient "container of bytes", which is exactly what it is.
- There are dozens of answers on SO showing you how to go the other way; just search for "hexify".

Answer (score 2):

Converting the hexadecimal string to a character string can be done by using [`std::substr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) to get the next two characters of the hex string, then using [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) to convert the substring to an integer. This can be casted to a character that is added to a `std::string`. The `std::stoi` function is C++11 only, and if you don't have it you can use e.g. [`std::strtol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtol).

To do the opposite you loop over each character in the input string, cast it to an integer and put it in an [`std::ostringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream) preceded by manipulators to have it presented as a [two-digit](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw), [zero-prefixed](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setfill) [hexadecimal number](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/hex). Append to the output string.

Use [`std::string::c_str`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) to get an old-style C `char` pointer if needed.

No external library, only using the C++ standard library.

Comment: -1 Why post the code that the OP explicitly asked you to **NOT** post?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Ah, modified answer to be textual only.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are talking about ASCII codes. Well, first step is to find the size of `b`. Assuming you have all characters by 2 hexadecimal digits (for example, a <kbd>tab</kbd> would be `09`), then size of `b` is simply `strlen(a) / 2 + 1`.

That done, you need to go through letters of `a`, 2 by 2, convert them to their integer value and store it as a string. Written as a formula you have:

```
b[i] = (to_digit(a[2*i]) << 4) + to_digit(a[2*i+1]))
```

where `to_digit(x)` converts `'0'-'9'` to `0-9` and `'a'-'z'` or `'A'-'Z'` to `10-15`.

Note that if characters below `0x10` are shown with only one character (the only one I can think of is <kbd>tab</kbd>, then instead of using `2*i` as index to `a`, you should keep a `next_index` in your loop which is either added by 2, if `a[next_index] < '8'` or added by 1 otherwise. In the later case, `b[i] = to_digit(a[next_index])`.

The reverse of this operation is very similar. Each character `b[i]` is written as:

```
a[2*i] = to_char(b[i] >> 4)
a[2*i+1] = to_char(b[i] & 0xf)
```

where `to_char` is the opposite of `to_digit`.

Comment: how to convert the two chars ("6f" for example) to integer 0x6f

Comment: you have two characters `'6'` and `'f'`. The `to_digit` function should convert `'6'` to `6` and `'f'` to `15`. Once you have that, then `0x6f` is just `(6 << 4) + 15`.

Answer (score 1):

Forward:

1. Read two hex chars from input.
2. Convert to int (0..255). (hint: sscanf is one way)
3. Append int to output char array
4. Repeat 1-3 until out of chars.
5. Null terminate the array

Reverse:

1. Read single char from array
2. Convert to 2 hexidecimal chars (hint: sprintf is one way).
3. Concat buffer from (2) to final output string buffer.
4. Repeat 1-3 until out of chars.

Almost forgot to mention. stdio.h and the regular C-runtime required only-assuming you're using `sscanf` and `sprintf`. You could alternatively create a a pair of conversion tables that would radically speed up the conversions.

Answer (score 0):

Each hexadecimal digit corresponds to 4 bits, because 4 bits has 16 possible bit patterns (and there are 16 possible hex digits, each standing for a unique 4-bit pattern).

So, two hexadecimal digits correspond to 8 bits.

And on most computers nowadays (some Texas Instruments digital signal processors are an exception) a C++ `char` is 8 bits.

This means that each C++ `char` is represented by 2 hex digits.

So, simply read two hex digits at a time, convert to `int` using e.g. an `istringstream`, convert that to `char`, and append each `char` value to a `std::string`.

The other direction is just opposite, but with a twist.

Because `char` is signed on most systems, you need to convert to `unsigned char` before converting that value again to hex digits.

Comment: would you give an example for hello word please

Answer (score 0):

Conversion to and from hexadecimal can be done using `hex`, like e.g.

```
cout << hex << x;
cin >> hex >> x;
```

for a suitable definition of `x`, e.g. `int x`

This should work for string streams as well.

Comment: No, this is not what those do. Please read the question again.